# Excel: Conditional extension of average function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, how to extend the average function conditionally such that

```
B1= AVERAGE(A1:A5), B2=AVERAGE(A6:A10), B3=AVERAGE(A11:A15),
```

and so on and not

```
B1= AVERAGE(A1:A5), B2=AVERAGE(A2:A6), B3=AVERAGE(A3:A7),...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a calculated reference with the OFFSET function. In B1 enter the following formula :

```
    =AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$1:$A$5,5*(ROW()-1),0))
```

and copy down.